# read JSON - sort by - and display

Tags: json, sorting, output

I am a beginner in Javascript.
Sorry for my question.
I would like to read  a json file, then I will s sort by call,
(see my repeatermap.json file) and list it.
I have made a mistake, but I did not found it.

Can anyone help me?

repeatermap.json

```
{"relais":[
{"id":1347,"call":"GB3WX-10","locator":"IO81VC","mode":"FM","rx":50.52,"tx":29.21,"remarks":"CTCSS tone is 77 Hz","qth":"MERE WILTSHIRE","url":"https://www.ukrepeater.net/my_repeater.php?id=1026","el":"","lon":-2.191317,"lat":51.098848},
{"id":2282,"call":"DB0FGB","locator":"JO50WB","mode":"DStar","rx":29.22,"tx":29.22,"remarks":"","qth":"Schneeberg","url":"http://www.db0fgb.de/","el":"","lon":11.852833333333,"lat":50.051333333333},
{"id":2403,"call":"DB0GSH","locator":"JO51EV","mode":"FM","rx":432.875,"tx":29.61,"remarks":"CTCSS 88,5 Hz","qth":"Steinberg","url":"","el":"","lon":10.406166666667,"lat":51.907166666667},
{"id":3762,"call":"DB0RX","locator":"JN58WG","mode":"FM","rx":29.61,"tx":29.61,"remarks":"Simplex, CTCSS 67Hz","qth":"Riexing  bei Niederneuching","url":"http://www.ov-erding.de/html/funk.html","el":"","lon":11.86106,"lat":48.25602},
{"id":1,"call":"DM0MAX","locator":"JO42IG","mode":"FM","rx":29.52,"tx":29.62,"remarks":"CTCSS TX 79,7 wenn SQL offen. RX nicht verriegelt. Öffnen durch CTCSS 79,7Hz 300ms oder DTMF * oder SQL offen 200ms","qth":"Wiehengebirge","url":"http://www.dm0max.de","el":"","lon":8.701853,"lat":52.2905}
]}
```

```
    var json = { relais: [] };
    var url="repeatermap.json";
    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
        json = data;
    })

    $.each(json.relais,function(i,row){ 
        document.write(row.call + "<br>");
    });
 

    function sortResults(prop, asc) {
        arr.sort(function(a, b) {
            if (asc) {
                return (a[prop] > b[prop]) ? 1 : ((a[prop] < b[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
            } else {
                return (b[prop] > a[prop]) ? 1 : ((b[prop] < a[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
            }
        });
        renderResults();
    }
```

my solution:

```
var erg;
$.getJSON("repeatermap.json", function(data) {

    erg = sortJSON(data.relais,'call', '123'); 
    
    for (var i = 0; i < erg.length; i++) {
        var r = erg[i];
        document.write("Call: "+r.call+"<br>");
    }
    
});

function sortJSON(arr, key, way) {
        return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
        if (way === '123') { return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0)); }
        if (way === '321') { return ((x > y) ? -1 : ((x < y) ? 1 : 0)); }
    });
}
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that you "have made a mistake"?  What evidence do you have that `sortResults` is being called at all?

Comment: I have tried some variations. But it don't work for me. The sort function is not active yet. I did not find my mistake

Comment: What *precisely* do you mean by "it don't work for me"?  What did it DO, and how was that different from what you expected?